# RDF Reactor and Individual extraction

Tags: java, rdf, owl, ontology

I'm working with Ontologies. I want to dynamically convert ontology classes into Java classes. I'm using the "RDF Reactor" that permit me to create Java classes. It works well in building all ".java" files according to classes of the ontology but Individuals are not extracted.
Is there a way to create Java classes and at same time instantiate Individuals as Java Object of previously created classes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This might be answered in the [FAQ](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/RDFReactor/FAQ), although it's not clear whether or not this is supposed to handle individuals declared in the ontology or not.

> #### [If I have an RDF2Go model, how can I get a collection or iterator over all instances of a given type as a RDFReactor instances?](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/RDFReactor/FAQ#If_I_have_an_RDF2Go_model.2C_how_can_I_get_a_collection_or_iterator_over_all_instances_of_a_given_type_as_a_RDFReactor_instances.3F)
>
> If
>   you generated the class Person, then Person.getAllInstances( model )
>   gives you an array of Person back.